# Object of type ImageForm is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I wanted to post image processing from views to celery, but it shows me a JSON-related problem
**"Object of type ImageForm is not JSON serializable"**

Here the code from **models.py**

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    sec_title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload_p/', blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.img.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageModel
        fields = ('title', 'img', 'sec_title')
```

**views.py**

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_w = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_w.is_valid():
            water_mark.delay(form_w)
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'Luki/upload_img.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def water_mark(form_w):
    instance = form_w.save(commit=False)
    cd = form_w.cleaned_data['img']

    if instance.img:
        im = Image.open(instance.img)

        width, height = im.size
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        text = "TEST WATERMARK"

        font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36)
        textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text, font)

        # calculate the x,y coordinates of the text
        margin = 10
        x = width - textwidth - margin
        y = height - textheight - margin

        draw.text((x, y), text, font=font)


        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        print('BYTES IO: ', thumb_io)
        im.save(thumb_io, im.format, quality=100)
        instance.img.save(str(cd), ContentFile(thumb_io.getvalue()), save=False)

    instance.save()

    return redirect('Luki:gallery')
```

Of course, all the libraries are imported and the code from the views without celera is executed and it looks like this. This works so that the photo you add in the form gets a watermark, saves it and takes you to the gallery.

**views.py**

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_w = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_w.is_valid():
            instance = form_w.save(commit=False)
            cd = form_w.cleaned_data['img']

            if instance.img:
                im = Image.open(instance.img)

                width, height = im.size
                draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
                text = "TEST WATERMARK"

                font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36)
                textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text, font)

                # calculate the x,y coordinates of the text
                margin = 10
                x = width - textwidth - margin
                y = height - textheight - margin

                # draw watermark in the bottom right corner
                draw.text((x, y), text, font=font)

                thumb_io = BytesIO()
                im.save(thumb_io, im.format, quality=100)
                instance.img.save(str(cd), ContentFile(thumb_io.getvalue()), save=False)

            instance.save()


            return redirect('Luki:gallery')
    else:
        form_w = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'Luki/upload_img.html', {
        'form_w': form_w,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this [blog](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-celery-rabbitmq), you can not pass object in celery.

> Since Celery is a distributed system, you can't know in which process,
> or even on what machine the task will run. So you shouldn't pass
> Django model objects as arguments to tasks, its almost always better
> to re-fetch the object from the database instead, as there are
> possible race conditions involved.

So in your case, save the image in model in view itself and pass pk of the model to celery task, and then fetch those details again from the model.

Comment: So I usually save the photo in views and it goes to the database and then download the pk of this object and send it to the celery?

Comment: yes... correct... in celery you can get the object of `ImageModel` using pk.

Comment: I tried and passed the object to the celery but I don't know how to upload this watermarked picture again with celery. I have an error like: **set_nonblocking() on a file object with no setblocking() method (Windows pipes don't support non-blocking I/O)**

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code with **tasks.py** looks like and I still have an error.

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_w = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # files = request.FILES.getlist('img')
        if form_w.is_valid():
            wm = form_w.save()
            water_mark.delay(wm.pk)


            return redirect('Luki:gallery')
    else:
        form_w = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'Luki/upload_img.html', {
        'form_w': form_w,
    })
```

And **tasks.py**

```
def water_mark(wm):
    instance = ImageModel.objects.get(id=wm)

    # im = Image.open(instance.img)
    # print('im before saving: ', im)

    # Writes the image correctly
    # im.save('Luki/media/upload_p/zzzta.jpg')


    if instance.img:
        # upload_p/img-8945.jpg
        print('img before opening: ', instance.img)
        # returns upload_p/img-8945.jpg

        im = Image.open(instance.img)
        print('img after: ', im)
        # returns <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1920x1080 at 0x5AD75F0>


        width, height = im.size
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        text = "TEST WATERMARK"

        font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36)
        textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text, font)

        # calculate the x,y coordinates of the text
        margin = 10
        x = width - textwidth - margin
        y = height - textheight - margin

        # draw watermark in the bottom right corner
        draw.text((x, y), text, font=font)

        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        print('BYTES IO: ', thumb_io)
        im.save(thumb_io, im.format, quality=100)

        # FieldFile.save(name, content, save=True)
        instance.img.save(str('zzjca.jpg'), ContentFile(thumb_io.getvalue()), save=False)

    instance.save()
```

And it returns an error
`File "f:\python\portfoliolk\venv\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 100, in set_nonblocking raise NotImplementedError("set_nonblocking() on a file object " NotImplementedError: set_nonblocking() on a file object with no setblocking() method (Windows pipes don't support non-blocking I/O)`

I don't know if it's not windows fault...